# windows phone 8 navigation: Device Physical Button Issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

When navigation between pages, I pressed either start or search button which will bring me out from the app. Then when I come back to the app. It says Navigation Service null or something similar to it.

How could i solve it!?

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
                {
                    TextBlock b = (TextBlock)sender;

                    var CusId = (TextBlock)b.FindName("CusId");
                    var SCHTime1 = (TextBlock)b.FindName("pschtime");
                    int intCusId = Convert.ToInt32(CusId.Text);
                    string ScheduleTime = SCHTime1.Text;

                    LoginVM.GetCustomerDetail(intCusId);

                    if (LoginVM.OBCustomerDetail.Count != 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var c in LoginVM.OBCustomerDetail)
                        {
                            Common.CustomerNetworkId = c.CustomerNetworkId;
                            Common.intCustomerId = c.Id;
                            Common.CustomerName = c.Name;
                            Common.RouteId = c.RouteId.Value;
                            Common.strReportedTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Hours + ":" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Minutes;

                        }
                        getVisitDetailNo();

                        if (VN == false)
                        {
                            myPopup.IsOpen = false;
                            backstatus = false;
                            return;
                        }
                        if (Common.visitDetailNo == null)
                        {
                            return;
                        }

                        if (LoginVM.SaveVisitedCustomer(Common.visitDetailNo, Common.strVisitHeaderNo, Common.RouteId, Common.intCustomerId, Common.SPOAccId, Common.intSalesRepId, Common.intAreaSalesManagerAccId, Common.intAreaSalesManagerId, Common.strTransactionDate, ScheduleTime, Common.strReportedTime) == true)
                        {
                            //update next Visit Detail No
                            if (UpdateVisitConfigTable() == true)
                            {
                                myPopup.IsOpen = false;
                                backstatus = false;
                                Common.urlstring = "/View/frmCustomerMenu.xaml";
                                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/LoadingView.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

                                configVM = new ConfigViewModel();

                                //Bind Visited Outlets
                                bindVisited();
                            }
                            else
                        }
                    }


                });
```

The above will direct to loading.aspx and its code as below

```
GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate() {
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(Common.urlstring, UriKind.Relative));
            });
```

error comes from the loading.aspx even though i navigate away from the page before that.

![enter image description here][1]

Highlighted in Yellow-
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(Common.urlstring, UriKind.Relative));

Common.urlstring = "/View/frmFirstTimeSync.xaml"

NavigationService = Null according to error

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=95ecd7b

I cannot post pictures because I do not have enough reputation

Comment: You need to post the exception that you are getting and the surrounding code. Are you trying to call the NavigationService in the page's Constructor? perhaps move it into the protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) method if this is the case

Comment: But would this help when start or search button press? because im using a dispatcher to do my process and in the end of my process it navigates to another page inside dispatcher.

Comment: Add some code to your question, anyone would need to see the block of code where you are performing the navigation.

Comment: post the exception messages and point lines at which there are thrown.

Comment: Added the pic as a link

Comment: I have added the NavigateTo Method It works yet it gives an error sometimes System.InvalidOperationException and rarely it stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Above Question Runs **FormLoad** Method. I changed the Navigation Service Location.

Now the Navigation service works in **OnNavigatedTo** Method. It works Fine